# Raspberry Pi 3B+ with LEDs WS2812B and speaker

Tags: speakers, ws2812

I just started making my first project with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and I found an amazing tutorial ("https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/"). I am curious if there is any way to control RGB LEDs ws2812b and in the same time use speaker with one RP3B+. And if not, can I do that using additional Arduino connected to LEDs?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that you can use WS2812b LED and play audio at the same time.  It is not clear if you would like to manually use the Rpi stretch's preinstalled  very popular VLC Media Player to play say, a mp3 audio file, or if you would like to use Python to control both LED and sound at the same time.  You may like to let us know how would you like to use the speaker. BTW, the tutorial you mentioned is indeed very good.

Comment: I would like to use it as cloud speaker (probably with Spotify) and simultaneously control LEDs connected to RP3b+ with Python code. So, it will be two completely independent "programs" run simultaneously.

Comment: ，thanks for clarifying that you wish to run two independent "programs".  Then I am 90% sure it is a piece of cake for Rpi, because Rpi with Raspbian "Operatinging System (OS)" is a "Multiprocessing/Multiprogramming (MP) OS", like Windows 7/10, can handle different independent "programs" at the same time.  Just try Spotify and run python WS2812b at the same time, and let me (need to add "@" on my name to draw my attention) know if you have any problems.  PS - If you wish to use python to control two "independent" programs, it is still possible, but a bit hard for newbies.